# Confused about MusicService

Tags: android, android-service, android-music-player

I've built a music player which is running on a Service. 
I'm preforming various actions as play, pause, next song, previous song etc through a binding to the service from my activity.

It works totally fine.

So to my question:
Is it ideal to put the service on a new thread? I know Service run by default on Main/UI thread.
If not, how do I know when to actually put something on a new thread? Can I put the whole Service instance on new thread or just a part of the code in the Service?

I guess this is called a long running service, shouldnt that be on a own thread to not block the UI?

When debugging I can see this in Logcat: I/Choreographer(691): Skipped 60 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread...
That got me wondering too! :o

As my title says, I'm very confused about this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, Services are not threads (they do not create a different thread).
When started form an activity they would block the main/UI thread fi running long operations.
you can use `IntentService` - which start their own thread to perform background long running operations - but that would probably suits a download file task or long running calculation better than playing music.
note that `IntentService` creates and destroys the thread by itself (when the work is done).

Another option would be to create you own thread manually.

**That said, I would consider this article:**
**http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html**
It talks about a service in the foreground using `startForeground()` which adds a notification to the status bar, letting the user be aware of the fact that the service is running - as well as promoting the service so it won't get destroyed in case of low memory conditions (it could be - but it will probably be the last one to be closed).
the example is about running media player while taking the main thread blocking into consideration as well as handling system events to pause and play music as expected (using `BroadcastReceiver` )

**Also note this:**
**http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html**

> Should you use a service or a thread?
>
> A service is simply a component that can run in the background even
>   when the user is not interacting with your application. Thus, you
>   should create a service only if that is what you need.
>
> If you need to perform work outside your main thread, but only while
>   the user is interacting with your application, then you should
>   probably instead create a new thread and not a service. For example,
>   if you want to play some music, but only while your activity is
>   running, you might create a thread in onCreate(), start running it in
>   onStart(), then stop it in onStop(). Also consider using AsyncTask or
>   HandlerThread, instead of the traditional Thread class. See the
>   Processes and Threading document for more information about threads.
>
> Remember that if you do use a service, it still runs in your
>   application's main thread by default, so you should still create a new
>   thread within the service if it performs intensive or blocking
>   operations.